# Spring Data JPA: Cannot save entity with composite primary key which contains foreign key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-bean

Stumped, utterly stumped...

Assume two entities, Parent and Child, with many Child entities to one Parent. Parent's primary key is of type `java.util.UUID`, and Child's primary key is a composite of the Parent's UUID and a sequence number.

The short of the issue is when I try to save a new Child using `childRepository.save(child)`, I get the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of
>   type [com.package.entities.ParentEntity$$_jvst149_0] to required type
>   [java.util.UUID] for property 'parent': PropertyEditor
>   [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.UUIDEditor] returned
>   inappropriate value of type
>   [com.package.entities.ParentEntity_$$_jvst149_0]

Please look at my classes below. The best I can tell I am following the `JPA` spec correctly, so I'm wondering if this is a bug in `Spring Data JPA`, perhaps specific to UUID type IDs (similar thing has happened before, see [DATAJPA-269](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-269))

Note I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 1.4.1.RELEASE`

Parent.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID id;

    //...other fields, getters + setters...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Parent that = (Parent) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

Child.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@IdClass(ChildKey.class)
public class Child implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Parent parent;
    @Id
    private Integer seqNum;

    //...other fields, getters + setters...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Child that = (Child) o;
        return Objects.equals(parent, that.parent) &&
                Objects.equals(seqNum, that.seqNum);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(parent, seqNum);
    }
}
```

ChildKey.class

```
public class ChildKey implements Serializable {

    private UUID parent;
    private Integer seqNum;

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ChildKey that = (ChildKey) o;
        return Objects.equals(parent, that.parent) &&
                Objects.equals(seqNum, that.seqNum);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(parent, seqNum);
    }
}
```

ParentRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, UUID> {
}
```

ChildRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface ChildRepository extends CrudRepository<Child, ChildKey> {
}
```

And finally, the code I execute:

```
@Transactional
public void createChild(Parent parent) {
    // needed to do this to get over "detached entity passed to persist"
    parent = parentRepository.getOne(parent.getId());
    child = new Child();
    child.setParent(parent);
    child.setSeqNum(1);
    childRepository.save(child);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Many-To-One relationship your child entity has it's own ID, and ID from parent entity is FK not a part of PK.
[Example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne)

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate the answer, but i don't think i follow. In every RDBMS I have used, I have never had a problem with a child's primary key being composed of a foreign key -- in fact, that is a common tactic to normalize your database.

Answer (score 0):

In the months since I posted this question, I have not found a suitable answer. I unfortunately had to work around the issue by not using `@ManyToOne` and instead just reference the parent by UUID:

```
public class Child implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private UUID parentId;
    @Id
    private Integer seqNum;
```

I leave JPA ignorant of the foreign key and just let the database throw an error should i violate reference integrity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your ChildKey class:

```
public class ChildKey implements Serializable {

    private Parent parent; // <-- Parent type instead of UUID
    private Integer seqNum;
    ...
```

UPD: I read JPA spec. and understood that it is incorrect. But it works in my case.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks. I no longer work on the code base that inspired this question, but next time i try to do something like this i will try it.